# CSS 'float' vs. 'inline-block' in an unordered list

Tags: html-lists, css-float, css

i am struggling with the CSS of an unordered list which i want to use in order to provide links to a number of online profiles. the list is displayed in the footer of every page, like so (bottom right): http://www.alexbrunner.com.

my understanding is the following:

- either, i make use of the CSS property 'display:inline-block;' - but given its relatively poor cross-browser support i would prefer not to.
- or, i float the list and define the 'inline'-characteristic on the ul-level - here, however, is where my trouble begins.

if i float the li-elements left, it is obviously positioned on the wrong side of the text. if i float the li-elements right, obviously each item is floated to the right of the following item, which results in my list being **displayed in the reverse order**.

the html is:

```
<div id="footer-right">
<p>E-mail me at mail@alexbrunner.com<br />or visit my profiles at <ul id="profiles">
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/alexbrunner" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icons/16/facebook_bw.png" class="profile" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/109422064867262895187/about" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icons/16/googleplus_bw.png" class="profile" alt="Google plus" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.xing.com/profile/Alex_Brunner7" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icons/16/xing_bw.png" class="profile" alt="Xing" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://at.linkedin.com/in/abrunner/en" target="_blank"><img src="../images/icons/16/linkedin_bw.png" class="profile" alt="Linkedin" /></a></li>
</ul></p>
</div>
```

and the css is:

```
#footer-right { float:right; width:17em; border:0; border-top:1px dotted #333; text-align:right; margin:0; padding:1.25em 0; }
.profile { width:1em; height:1em; margin-left:0.3em; }
#footer-right p { display:inline; font-size:.75em; color:#666; }
#footer-right ul { display:inline; margin:0; padding:0; }
#profiles li { float:right; list-style:none; }
```

of course, i could just reverse the order in my html document and start with the last - but i really want to figure out what is the semantically correct way of doing this. i am sure there is a better way than what i have applied and i would really appreciate any comments on this.

eventually i want to put all those icons in a sprite - but i figure i have to solve this issue here first.

thank you!

best,
alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure from reading if this is what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/RSMFw/

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
#profiles li { display: inline; list-style:none; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AcTu7/1/

This should display semantically and you don't have to bother with floats.

Comment: i am not sure whether your way is any more or less elegant than justinlabenne's, but it seems to be equally valid.

Answer (score -1):

To maintain the desired display order, apply `float: left;` to ALL of the child elements of your `div#footer-right`, i.e: `#footer-right * { float: left;}`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wqneM/